# how to use async and await to connect to mongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, callback

I am new to JavaScript and currently learning mongoDB with node.
The code Bellow is in callback functions but i want to connect to mongoDB database using async and await with try and catch .

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/selfdb");

mongoose.connection
  .once("open", () => {
    console.log("connection has been made!");
  })
  .on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("connection error:", error);
  });
```

I tried doing this way:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

async function main() {
  const uri = "mongodb://localhost/selfdb";

  const client = new mongoose(uri);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log("connection has been made!");
  } catch (e) {
    client.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

but i got following error:

> TypeError: mongoose is not a constructor

how could i do it the right way?
am i doing any silly mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the better way to connect is like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

Mongo URI is in .env file, but you can replace it with your connection string (but more secure in  .env file)

Then in server.js or index.js (entry file)

```
const connectDB = require('path_to_file')

connectDB()
```

Answer (score 1):

I Tried this approach !! May be it could be helpful.

**DBconn.js (MONGO_URL is from .env file & dev_db_url is optional here)**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'env/.env' });
const dev_db_url = 'local dev. db url is not defined.';
const mongoDB_URL = process.env.MONGO_URL || dev_db_url;
const dbOptions = {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true};

const connectDB = async (cb) => {
    try {
     await mongoose.connect(mongoDB_URL, dbOptions)
        .then(() => {
            cb();
            console.log("Connected to Database");
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Could not Connect to Database", error)
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

**Server.js (Server will start to listen only after successful DB Connect)**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'env/.env' });
const connectDB = require('./database/DBConn')
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Connecting to DB
connectDB(()=>{
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Backend : NodeJS/express server started on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
});
```

**Another Way :**
**DBconn.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'env/.env' });

const dev_db_url = 'local dev. db url is not defined.';
const mongoDB_URL = process.env.MONGO_URL || dev_db_url;
const dbOptions = {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true};

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
     await mongoose.connect(mongoDB_URL, dbOptions);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Could not Connect to Database", error)
    }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

**Server.js (here we use .once method)**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'env/.env' });
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = require('./database/DBConn')
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

connectDB();
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Backend : NodeJS/express server started on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
});
```